# Read configuration from project being tested when running integrations test in dotnet core

Tags: .net, configuration

I followed [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/testing/integration-testing?view=aspnetcore-2.1) to setup an integration tests project in dotnet core 2.1

I have my projects configured like this:

```
$ dotnet sln list
Project reference(s)
--------------------
mtss-ws/mtss-ws.csproj
mtss-ws.integrationtests/mtss-ws.integrationtests.csproj

$ cd mtss-ws.integrationtests/
$ dotnet list mtss-ws.integrationtests.csproj reference
Project reference(s)
--------------------
..\mtss-ws\mtss-ws.csproj
```

And when creating my TestServer I have to load the configuration form the project begin tested. I tried with this:

```
public PingController_RunShould() {

    _server = new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder()
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((builderContext, config) => {
            config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
        })
        .UseStartup<Startup>());

    _client = _server.CreateClient();
}
```

But the system tries to find the `appsettings.json` file in `mtss-ws.integrationtests/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/appsettings.json`

I tried specifying `../mtss-ws/appsettings.json` buut it didn't work.

So far now I could solve it just creating a symlink to the desired config file, but I was wondering if there's some smarter way to solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kept researching a bit more and came up whit this solution:

```
private void SetUpClient()
{
    _server = new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseContentRoot(GetContentRootPath())
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((builderContext, config) => {
            config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
        })
        .UseStartup<Startup>());
    Client = _server.CreateClient();
}

private string GetContentRootPath() {
    var testProjectPath = PlatformServices.Default.Application.ApplicationBasePath;
    var relativePathToHostProject = @"../../../../mtss-ws";
    return Path.Combine(testProjectPath, relativePathToHostProject);
}
```

For more details about you can check [this](https://koukia.ca/integration-testing-in-asp-net-core-2-0-51d14ede3968) article,, and also [this one](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-core/1420/integration-testing-aspnet-core)